# Create tables with mixed content

Tags: xcode, uitableview, button, storyboard

I must create a table with five rows. The first row contains a label and switch button, the remaining 4 rows contain simply a label.
This table has not to be modified. 
Then, I used a storyboard to design table as specified above; now, I need a function to manage user's pressure on any row. Anyway, if I associate an UITableViewController class to my storyboard and run simulator, the table appears empty, because the methods of controller to fill rows have not been implemented. But I don't want to implement them, since my table has already been designed through the storyboard.
How can I design a controller simply managing my storyboard as it is, without defining functions trying to modify the structure I designed, but allowing to handle user's interactions as well?

If I loaded my storyboard into an UITableViewController through the use of function **instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier**, would I have my table as I designed it, giving labels/table/button an identifier? How could I manage user's interaction in this case? how could I access the table and its field/row numbers?

Alternatively, how could I create my table programmatically, with a label and a button on first row?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to easily use the standard switch cells, label cells, and other standard UI cells, then I'd strongly recommend you check out the free Sensible TableView framework. Should save you a ton of time.

Answer (score 0):

The tableview you designed with storyboard has a custom class, it's your view controller. Even you've finished the design of your tableview with storyboard, you still have to implement the delegate & datasource methods in your view controller. In your case, you need to implement "tableView:numberOfRowsInSection" to return 5, and "tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath" if your custom cells have different height.

You should create custom tableview cells to manage user's interaction.  Design the cells in storyboard, implement the logic in your custom UITableViewCell classes. Set the cell's custom class to your custom UITableViewCell classes. Pass users' interaction events to your  UITableViewController with delegate.

Create UITableView programmatically is not very different. Create an UITableView and add it as subview. Make sure you set self as the delegate and datasource of the tableview. Implement all the delegate & datasource methods in your ViewController. Create a custom UITableViewCell with  button and label programmatically, and return it in "tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath" when "indexPath.row == 0"